# How to ignore extra keyword arguments in Python?

Tags: python

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

def foo(d):
    return Test(**d)

# this works well
d = {'id': 'aaa', 'name': 'aaa-name'｝
foo(d)
# this would not work well, because of parameter variations, a external para     add into dict d. 
d = {'id': 'aaa', 'name': 'aaa-name', 'test1': 'test1'｝

# traceback
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test1'
```

Is there any methods to ignore the parameter variations of dict d?

Comment: You pass kwargs, but you don't handle them. Use **kwargs or something in the init signature

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with" the extra keyword args? Ignore them? Use them to set attributes of the object? Something else?

Comment: Ignore extra keyword args.

Answer (score 12):

You can make `Test.__init__` accept an extra `**kwargs`

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, **kwargs):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
```

Comment: That is half the answer. How to go from here?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I think that's enough, we can just ignore `kwargs`

Comment: Does it automatically assign to self from the keys in the dict?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: in all fairness the OP hasn't really explained what is meant by "deal with" the extra kwargs. At this point ignoring them is perfectly valid. Using them to set attributes on the object might also be valid.

Comment: @mhawke that's true. However in cases where it's not clear exactly what OP is asking, it's better to not answer at all until it's cleared up. Right now we can only guess

Comment: @TimCastelijns: fair enough. That's why I asked the OP what they wanted? Their response is that the extras should be ignored.

Answer (score 10):

This will do the trick, simply update the `self.__dict__`

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, **kwargs):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Example:

```
In[2]: class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, **kwargs):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
In[3]: d = {'id': 'aaa', 'name': 'aaa-name', 'test1': 'test1'}
In[5]: t = Test(**d)
In[6]: t.id
Out[5]: 'aaa'
In[7]: t.name
Out[6]: 'aaa-name'
In[8]: t.test1
Out[7]: 'test1'
```

**EDIT:**

To ignore the extras just dont use the kwargs as in @wong2 answer:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, **kwargs):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
```

Comment: Why not `def __init__(self, **kwargs): self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`?

Comment: @vaultah, he may want to force the id and the name to be forced int the params, so you really neead an id and a name

Comment: I want to ignore extra keyword args.

Comment: @Wilence see my answer